# Excel VBA Selenium to open local webpages runtime-error as well as out of memory error

Tags: vba, excel, firefox, selenium

I have a list of local `.HTM` files which I want to parse using `Selenium` in `VBA` (Excel 2013). I encounter two problems but first some sample code:

```
    Sub openSelenium()
        Dim html As HTMLDocument
        Dim selenium As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

        Set selenium = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
        selenium.Start "firefox", "about:blank"
        selenium.Open "file:///D:/webpages/LE_1001.htm"
        Set html = selenium.getHtmlSource
    End Sub
```

Basically what I want is to store the `HTML Source Code` of each local website which is to be parsed in a `HTMLDocument` element so I can work with the `HTMLDocument` since I'm familiar with it.
I use FireFox v43.0.2 and Excel 2013 on a Windows 7 Pro SP1.

**Problems:** the above code opens FireFox but goes to this webpage: "https://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/43.0.2/firstrun/learnmore/" and stops here.

1. the VBA freezes shortly and I receive the following message:
   [image]
2. I receive the Excel the `Out of memory` message. Sometimes I receive this message even after restarting the computer. But this doesn't happen that often. Point 1 is more of a problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the version of Mozilla Firefox. I **was using version 43.0.2**.  
After downgrading to **version 24.0** the code seemed to function properly. So I think the problem was most likely the FireFox version after all.
Selenium for VBA was updated in [Dec. 2013](https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/downloads/list) the last time so installing a [FireFox version](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) which was released in about the same time made it work properly.

**EDIT:** Just use SeleniumBasic and you will avoid all these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Firefox using default profile that is part of Firefox. Get default profile and open firefoxdriver. Here is [github URL](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/blob/master/Examples/VBScript/CustomProfileWith(Chrome).vbs)

```
 Class Script
        Dim driver

        Sub Class_Initialize        
            Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.FirefoxDriver")
            driver.SetProfile "default" 'Name of the profile
            driver.Get "https://mail.google.com/mail"
        End Sub

        Sub Class_Terminate
            driver.Quit
        End Sub
    End Class

    Set s = New Script
```

How to check profiles are there or not ? In Firefox ?

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Comment: thank you for your effort but this isn't what I was looking for. Actually the problem was solved after I downgraded Firefox to version 24,0 so I guess it had to do with the FireFox version,

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

```
C:\Users\your name\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\Scripts
```

Click on firefox and install .net framework

Go to:

```
  control panel/turn on off windows feature and select `.net framework 3.5`
```